# Проблема с устаревшими функциями session_is_registered, session_unregister?

Tags: php, сессия

На сервере 5.4.41, а скрипт на 5.3.
В скрипте используются устаревшие функции session_is_registered, session_unregister.
Мне нужно их оформить по новым стандартам.
Вот сам код:

```
function logoutUser() {
      if (session_is_registered ( SESSION_USER ))
        session_unregister ( SESSION_USER );
    }
```

Желательно реализовать это одобренными функциями `$_SESSION` и `session_start()`
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а в чём вопрос?

Comment: Как это можно решить? - это вопрос. И просьба желательно реализовать это одобренными функциями $_SESSION и session_start() Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, так?

```
session_start();

function logoutUser(){

  if (isset($_SESSION[SESSION_USER]))
   unset($_SESSION[SESSION_USER]);

}
```

Подробнее можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions)

Comment: Спасибо за столь быстрый ответ. Изменения произошли в работе скрипта и это радует. Только при попытке войти выдается, что выполнен выход. Можете еще помочь?

Comment: В вопросе был приведён код функции, отвечающий только за разлогивание пользователя. За вход, вероятно, отвечает другая функция. Её нужно смотреть. Если ответ по заданному вопросу верный, то отметьте его соответствующей галкой.

Answer (score 1):

Степан, выше тебе привели функцию logout. Логично что результатом будет выход. 
Для входа нужно просто проинициализировать $_SESSION[SESSION_USER] данными пользователя. Примерно так

```
session_start();

function loginUser($session_user){

if (!isset($_SESSION[SESSION_USER]))
  $_SESSION[SESSION_USER]) = $session_user;
}
```